layout design doesnt show anything for xml files of my layouts in android studio
i tried to import one of my old projects(it was for 3 years ago) and update it to continue working on it. but the xml files that show the layouts i made doesnt show anything( activities or regular xml designs even. its just an empty black screen.
i tried to changing build tools, java versions, compile and target sdk, updating dependencies, invalidate cache and restart, clean project then rebuild projects and other things but it doesnt fixed yet. what should i have to do
i dont have any errors. here some pictures.



did you try running the app? What warning or errors do you get? check the AppTheme . Go to Attributes -> Theme and ensure it’s set to a valid theme. you may deprecated attributes, check for those as well.
Create a new layout file and copy-paste the content from the problematic file to the new one. This can sometimes resolve rendering issues

@PeterKapenaPeter yes i tried to run the app and its okay. no build error. my problem is just for showing the layout in android studio. i tried changing  theme several times also and refreshing the render each time but didnt work. i also created a new activity in gallery of android studio but the problem is still there

Also i tried to make a xml layout in a new project ( like main activity) and that was okay. The layout was showing things corrected.
